# proving a function has a unique stationary point

Tags: calculus

let p(x) be a twice differentiable concave increasing function defined on the non-negative reals that satisfies:

$p(0)=0$

$p(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

$p'(x)>0$ and $p''(x)<0$ everywhere

then define $f(x) = \frac{x p(x)}{2 p(x)-1}$ if $p(x)>1/2$ and undefined otherwise.

it's easy to see that f tends to infinity as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and as $x \rightarrow p^{-1}(1/2)$ from above, and is continuous, so it has a minimum point somewhere.

is this stationary point necessarily unique?

if you try differentiating f you get

$f'(x) = \frac{2p(x)^2-p(x)-xp'(x)}{(2p(x)-1)^2}$

and i don't see how this necessarily has a unique root

$f''(x) = \frac{x(1-2p(x))p''(x)+2p'(x)(2xp'(x)-2p(x)+1)}{(2p(x)-1)^3}$

we want this to be strictly positive on the range $x>p^{-1}(1/2)$. the first term in the numerator is always positive, but the second term would be positive iff $xp'(x)-p(x)>-1/2$ which i'm pretty sure doesn't hold as x gets big. i can show that it's between 0 and -1 which isn't good enough.

if you try various examples for p(x) such as $p(x)=1-a^{-x}$ and $p(x)=1-(x+1)^{-a}$ for a positive constant a, and plot them, they all seem to work. is it true or false in general for any p(x)? what if we drop the condition that p(0)=0 and only require $0<p(0)<1/2$?

(not homework, by the way. i'll give the motivation for the question if asked for)